# What is an Elegant Breadboard

Tags: terminology

There are quite a few documents on the internet which use the term Elegant BreadBoard (EBB) with no explanation of what it actually is.  I've been trawling the net trying to find out the difference between an EBB and a normal breadboard to no avail.  Sometimes it sounds like a PCB with all the components in.

Many of the papers are to do with lasers and the European Space Agency.  I know what a breadboard is but what makes it elegant or is EBB a standalone term which means something completely different?

Comment: It sounds like an [oxymoron](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oxymoron) to me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to a Swiss Space Center [Call for Proposals 2016](https://www.sbfi.admin.ch/dam/sbfi/en/dokumente/now_open_mdp_callforproposals2016.pdf):

> Elegant Breadboard: EB refers to an equipment between a BB and EM. It is built using commercial grade components and a configuration close to that of the FM. In other words, it is not a BB with physically separated units interconnected by cables and wires but a fully integrate unit in a configuration and with interfaces representative of the FM. There are no specific requirements for configuration and interface control.

Where BB is a Breadboard Model, EM is an Engineering Model and FM is a Flight Module. So it's one of a number of interim stages of prototype development.

Comment: It's also called, in some circles, an EDU (Engineering Development Unit).

Comment: Reminds me of an EE I used to work with who made the most beautiful prototypes on perfboard.